# How does a server detect whether sort of automated http request is being made

Tags: python, python-requests

I was making some test http requests using Python's request library. When searching for Walmart's Canadian site ([www.walmart.ca](http://www.walmart.ca)), I got this:

[image: Walmart Are you human]

How do servers like Walmart's detect that my request is being made programatically? I understand browsers send all sorts of metadata to the server. I was hoping to get a few specific examples of how this is *commonly* done. I've found a similar question, albeit related to Selenium Web Driver, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) where it claims that there are some vendors that provide this service but I was hoping to get something a bit more specific.

Appreciate any insights, thanks.

Comment: real browser sends many different values - headers, cookies, data. It reads from server not only HTML but also images, CSS, JS, fonts. Browser can also run JavaScript which can get other information about browser - version, extensions, data in local storage, etc (i.e how you move mouse). And real human loads/visits pages with random delays and in rather in random order. And all there elements can be used to detect script. Servers may use very complex systems even Machine Learning (Artificial Intelligence) and use data from few mintues or hours to compare your behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a real browsers send many different values - headers, cookies, data. It reads from server not only HTML but also images, CSS, JS, fonts. Browser can also run JavaScript which can get other information about browser - version, extensions, data in local storage, etc (i.e how you move mouse). And real human loads/visits pages with random delays and in rather in random order. And all these elements can be used to detect a script. Servers may use very complex systems even Machine Learning (Artificial Intelligence) and use data from few mintues or hours to compare your behavior.